# How to give list param in Dapper

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a method that gets person's course info.
As in code first, we get a list of `courseIds` and then we write a query to get courses filtered by list of ids.

```
public List<Course> GetMyCourses(int id)
{
    string secQuery = "select CourseId From CourseUsers where UserId=@id";
    var list = db.Query<int>(secQuery, param: new { @id = id }).ToList();
    if(list.Count == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    string query = "select c.Id,c.Image,c.CourseStateId,c.Price,c.Title,c.TeacherId,u.UserName,u.Id from Courses as c inner join Users as u on u.Id=c.TeacherId ";
    foreach (var item in list.Select((value, index) => new { index, value }))
    {
        if (list.Count > 1)
        {
            if (item.index == 0)
            {
                query = query + " where c.Id IN (" + item.value;
            }
            if (item.index + 1 == list.Count)
            {
                query = query + "," + item.value + ")";
            }
            else
            {
                query = query + "," + item.value;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            query = query + " where c.Id=" + item.value;
        }
    }
```

I did like this and it is working, but is there any better way?

Comment: Do not concatenate your parameters this way.   It makes your queries vulnerable to SQL injection.  Dapper explains in its documentation how to properly pass parameters safely.

Comment: Why don't you just join in [CourseUsers] and make a single query?

Comment: Questions about improving working code are better asked on [CodeReview.SE].

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid sketchy logic, SQL injection issues and multiple calls to the database if you create a subquery:

```
select c.Id, c.Image, c.CourseStateId, c.Price, c.Title, c.TeacherId, u.UserName, u.Id 
from Courses as c 
inner join Users as u 
    on u.Id = c.TeacherId
where cu.Id IN( select CourseId From CourseUsers where UserId=@id);
```